# Can we use Server.MapPath in Bitmap?

Tags: asp.net, image, resize-image, mobile-controls

recently i created a webpage, where in i have a img tag, whose source is linked to another page, where i am resizing the image, whose name is being sent from the src from previous page in query string. but when i create the new object of bitmap, i gets the error, Parameter is not valid.

below is the code which holds image tag.

```
 <img src='/resize.aspx?file=PRO_06_11_Final-272.jpg&width=128&height=73' alt="Nothing" />
```

below is the code for the resize page where i am resizing image and sending the bitmap object through response

```
if (Request.QueryString["file"] != null)
        {

            int lnHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["height"]);
            int lnWidth = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["width"]);
            string imgUrl = Request.QueryString["file"].ToString();
            Bitmap bmpOut = null;
            try
            {
                Bitmap loBMP;
                loBMP = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath(imgUrl)); //Parameter is not valid.. error is thrown here.
                System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat loFormat = loBMP.RawFormat;
                decimal lnRatio;
                int lnNewWidth = 0;
                int lnNewHeight = 0;
                //-----If the image is smaller than a thumbnail just return it As it is----- 
                if ((loBMP.Width < lnWidth && loBMP.Height < lnHeight))
                {
                    lnNewWidth = loBMP.Width;
                    lnNewHeight = loBMP.Height;
                }
                if ((loBMP.Width > loBMP.Height))
                {
                    lnRatio = (decimal)lnHeight / loBMP.Height;
                    lnNewHeight = lnHeight;
                    decimal lnTemp = loBMP.Width * lnRatio;
                    lnNewWidth = (int)lnTemp;
                    if (lnNewWidth > 128)
                    {
                        lnNewWidth = 128;
                    }
                 }
                else
                {
                    lnRatio = (decimal)lnHeight / loBMP.Height;
                    lnNewHeight = lnHeight;
                    decimal lnTemp = loBMP.Width * lnRatio;
                    lnNewWidth = (int)lnTemp;
                    if (lnNewWidth < 75)
                    {
                        lnNewWidth = 75;
                    }
                }
                bmpOut = new Bitmap(lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOut);
                g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.DrawImage(loBMP, 0, 0, lnNewWidth, lnNewHeight);
                Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                bmpOut.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("CreateThumbnail :" + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
```

the above code works fine in local Machine on FileSystem, but when i put the same code on dev server, the application starts throwing message..

can anyone tell me what could be the cause for this problem only on dev server.

Comment: What's the "message" (Exception I assume)?

Comment: The error message can probably tell you what's causing the problem.  What is the error and on what line is it thrown?  What are the states of the objects relevant to it on that line?

Comment: Hi guys, the error message i am getting is System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid. at System.Drawing.Bitmap..ctor(String filename) at resize.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)

check the question (updated)

Comment: Hello, if the picture is in the root of the application then use Server.MapPath("~/" + imgUrl). If not then make sure you indicate the name of the full path before you include the pictures path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify a root folder for `Server.MapPath` it will add the location of the currently executing aspx file. You can read more at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
If Path doesn't start with a slash, the MapPath method returns a path relative to the directory of the .asp file being processed
```

As Hanlet mentioned you need to add an images root folder. So your code will become

```
string imgRoot = "~/images/";
try
{
    ...

    loBMP = new Bitmap(Server.MapPath(imgRoot + imgUrl));
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, actually i have the file saved on the root folder, so i am using Server.MapPath(imgUrl).. this didnt helped.
i also used Server.MapPath("~/"+imgUrl).. but still i am getting same error.. is it possible i save the image in memorystream and call the stream in bitmap.. can you help me with that code.. if it could help

Comment: If you know the image exists then try:  
1. Hardcode the image path to see if the problem is with Server.MapPath not creating the correct path or the Bitmap class  
2. Check if you have given .net enough permissions to read the file